# Display SHARE and LIKE button on lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-player

I have a music application for iOS and I managed to run my app in background and display all the information on lock screen, Now I want to display share and like button same as Apple Music player on lock screen. 
Would you please let me know if it is possible or not and how?

Comment: What language are you using? Perhaps you should include that, both as a tag and in the question itself.

Comment: @Anders When I'm talking about iOS development an Apple music for sure it is Objective-c.

Comment: @Niloufar It's not "for sure".  Although in fairness, the language tag is actually a bit inappropriate as you don't have code you need help with and you're surely not simply asking for code to be written for you.

Comment: @nhgrif Actually I ad the language tag as Anders asked for. And I don't want sample code. I'm just asking for guideline as I've tried some codes but I couldn't get any results.

Comment: Apple's applications can do things that other apps can't. This is one of them

Comment: @Paulw11 "Apple's applications can do things that other apps can't. This is one of them". Can you post a link to any official documentation that verifies this?

Comment: I can't post a link to documentation that says what you *can't* do. There is only documentation saying what you can. For example, the clock app and the calendar app can change their icon. There is no documentation saying that you can't do this, but it is obvious from a lack of documented API and the fact that our icon is a fixed image in your app bundle that you can't.   Similarly with adding actions to the lock screen. There is no documented API so you can't do it. What I was saying is that just because you see one of Apple's apps doing something it doesn't mean you app can do it